# Hide media playback controls in iOS 16 WKWebView

Tags: css, ios, wkwebview

HTML:

```html
<video id="video-stream" autoplay playsinline></video>
```

CSS:

```css
*::-webkit-media-controls {
  display: none !important;
  -webkit-appearance: none !important;
}
*::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
  display: none !important;
  -webkit-appearance: none !important;
}
*::-webkit-media-controls-play-button {
  display: none !important;
  -webkit-appearance: none !important;
}
*::-webkit-media-controls-start-playback-button {
  display: none !important;
  -webkit-appearance: none !important;
}
```

Some of the CSS above was removing play/pause buttons in iOS 15, but it no longer works in iOS 16 - the buttons show, and pause button disappears after some time once video stream starts.

Thank you!

Comment: Can confirm, also seeing this behaviour in ios 16 and not 15

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible the problematic  element has controls="false" on it?

I was experiencing the same behavior on my video but it resolved after omitting controls="false". I appreciate your example doesn't specify this but that's the only way I've been able to replicate the behavior specified in your post.

Comment: no, it doesn't. But we no longer use web views for calls anyway.